# Create Spinner for Category and Subcategory Format

Tags: android, json

I want to create spinner but in Category and subcategory format, using JSON parsing for set value in spinner and bellow is my JSON response

```
{"terms": [
    {
      "term_id": 44,
      "name": "Default",
      "childs": null
    },{
      "term_id": 586,
      "name": "Commercial &amp; Industrial",
      "childs": [
        {
          "term_id": 587,
          "name": "Automotive/Mechanical Equipment"   
        }
      ]
    }   
  ],"code": "terms_found"
}
```

When We create Spinner then displays Category name and bellow this name display Subcategory name. Please, anyone, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Customize your spinner layout and adapter class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243498/adding-sub-categories-in-spinner-in-android